# How to calculate the performance time of a thread group (End Time - Start Time) in JMeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am new to jmeter, can anyone guide/Help me on how to take the 
start time and end time (so I can calculate the total time taken for a 
thread to complete) of a thread group?

I have referred some links and apache JMeter user manual but I could not able to pick it.
I have used jmeter 2.12.
JMeter running in GUI Mode.

I have tested HTTPS request for download file form IIS File server with below procedure/Test Plan.

1. Created one thread is Performance
2. Added Transaction Controller (child of parent thread)
3. Added HTTP Request, Aggregate Report listner and view Result tree( Child of Transaction Controller)

Do I need to use any plugin or other JMeter listeners to calculate the performance time?
Here I could not able to get the total performance time.Please can you do needful.

Answer (score 1):

In Jmeter you can provide test duration for your test. This is one way of knowing performance test time.

Other way could be reading start time and end time for a thread or threadgroup (If you have multiple threads under a single threadgroup) from log file or jtl file.

While doing actual load testing never use GUI. It takes lot of memory and cpu(OOM issue). See at best practices [Link](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/42699-jmeter-best-practices). In non-gui `-l` option can let you provide jtl file name which contains details of execution from that file. you can find out total test duration if it is not specified.